# How do I upload a simple one page website files to a canister on ICP that I already created using the Network Nervous System?

Tags: motoko

I created a canister using the NNS and funded it also.

Now, I want to upload a simple one page website.

I created the a main.mo file that calls the html file. I created a CSS file for the html.

I put these files in a directory called assets.

Now, can someone help me compile and deploy this to my canister that I already created using the NNS?

I've installed the IC SDK and dfx as well, on Linux.

Thanks!